# If we change the infinite series (or power series) so we are adding two terms at a time, is this still the same as the original series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I would like to ask about the second equality in this proof:

[image]

So the only difference between these two series, is that we are adding two terms at a time and I can actually imagine situation where the left hand side fails to converge but the right hand side converges using some alternating series.

For that reason, I would like to ask when are we allowed to change a series (or power series) like this and why is it ok in this specific case?

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct is right that you can start with a convergent series (like the left-hand side) and then proceed to group the terms two at a time (like the right-hand side), but not the other way around.

The convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, by definition, means that the limit of its partial sums $s_N = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ exists. The regrouped series converges, again by definition, precisely when the limit of its partial sums $t_N = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N (a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})$ converges. But $t_N = s_{2N+1}$ is a subsequence of a convergent sequence, so it converges to the same limit.

As for the failure in the other direction, you're right that there are simple alternating counterexamples like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$.

Comment: You answer the original question (good!). But I am not quite sure why the OP didn't ask about the next equality, the one justified by Th. 7.95(a). In general that's the step that needs care when we try to split up series.